# Ruby 2.3.0 - warning: circular argument reference - now

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On running  `rake db:migrate`, I am getting following error.

> /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:268: warning: circular argument reference - now

Comment: Can we have more backtrace of your error . Want to see from where it's being raised .

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you use a Ruby version that is too new for the version of Rails you have. Try updating Rails to a higher version.

Here are the general guidelines from the Rails site:

> Rails 5 requires Ruby 2.2.2 or newer.
>
> Rails 4 prefers Ruby 2.0 and requires 1.9.3 or newer.
>
> Rails 3.2.x is the last branch to support Ruby 1.8.7.
>
> Rails 3 and above require Ruby 1.8.7 or higher. Support for all of the previous Ruby versions has been dropped officially. You should upgrade as early as possible.